# Running a function within a .ts file that is triggered by a button inside of a separate .tsx file

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, html, react

My issue is that there is an html button that exists inside of my. tsx file, and I cannot get a function to fire When that button is clicked. The tricky part is that I need for a function that exists within a separate .ts to trigger when the button is clicked.

Inside of my .ts file I am importing my .tsx file as myButtonClass.
Inside of the default class within my .ts file, I am attempting to run the function myFunction and receiving the error message:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading'addEventListener')

```
import buttonClass from './components/buttonClass';

const buttonReference = document.getElementsByTagName('myButton')[0] as buttonElement;
buttonReference.addEventListener('click', this.myFunction);
```

My hypothesis is that intiailizing my buttonReference is not working. Any advice on how I can call the myFunction within my .tsx file would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that your button may not actually be rendered yet when the code in your `.ts` file is executed, so your `getElementsByTagName` doesn't actually find anything.

In order to ensure that the button is connected to the function, I would do it the other way around. In your `.ts` file, `export` the function you want to call.  Then in your `.tsx` file, `import` the function, and then you can trigger it from your button's click event handler.